# ArrayOf when using List<T> with a WCF Rest Service

Tags: .net, list, wcf, rest

I am trying to create a REST web service using .NET 4.0 and WCF. My REST service is returning a List which then gets serialized into XML. The problem I am having is that the XML being returned starts with ArrayOf, which I don't like.

In other words, right now the XML looks like this:

```
<ArrayOfAchievement>
    <Achievement>
        ...
    </Achievement>
</ArrayOfAchievement>
```

I would prefer to have the XML look like this:

```
<Achievements>
    <Achievement>
        ...
    </Achievement>
</Achievements>
```

If I create a new class and call it AchievementsList, which has a property of List< Achievement>, like so:

```
public class AchievementsList
{
    public List<Achievement> Achievements { get; set; }
}
```

Then have my service return the above class instead of List< Achievement>, the XML ends up looking like this:

```
<AchievementsList>
    <Achievements>
        <Achievement>
            ...
        </Achievement>
    </Achievements>
</AchievementsList>
```

Which is wrong (because it adds another level that doesn't belong there).

The other problem is that I also need to apply a namespace to the object, like so:

```
[XmlRoot(Namespace="NameSpaceURL")]
public class AchievementsList
{
    public List<Achievement> Achievements { get; set; }
}
```

Which I can't do if I just return a List< Achievement>.

So what can I do about these 2 problems?

Bara

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. You're on the right track with the `AchievementList` class, but what you need to do is decorate the `Achievements` list property with the `XmlElement` attribute, and supply the name of the individual elements.
2. The namespace goes on the `AchievementList` class, just like you have it.

Sample code:

```
[Serializable]
public class Achievement {
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
[XmlRoot(ElementName="Achievements", Namespace="http://www.mynamespace.com")]
public class AchievementList
{      
    [XmlElement("Achievement")]
    public List<Achievement> Achievements { get; set; }

    public AchievementList()
    {
        Achievements = new List<Achievement>();
    }

    public void Add(Achievement a)
    {
        Achievements.Add(a);
    }
}
```

And your output will be something like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<Achievements xmlns="http://www.mynamespace.com">
  <Achievement>
    <Name>Woke Up</Name>
  </Achievement>
  <Achievement>
    <Name>Went to work</Name>
  </Achievement>
  <Achievement>
    <Name>Slacked off</Name>
  </Achievement>
</Achievements>}
```

Comment: When I add the ElementName attributes, nothing happens.  Here's my code: http://screencast.com/t/MGJkY2MxY ... If I change it so that the element name is changed by the DataContract and DataMember, it does some odd things. Here's the code in that case: http://screencast.com/t/MGZkY2M0O ... And the result: http://screencast.com/t/OWYxYmRlZmQt

Comment: `[XmlElement("Achievement")]` only sets the the child element of Achievements to "Achievement" -- it still leaves you with 3 levels of elements.

Comment: I tested the code I posted before suggesting it, and the output is a copy & paste of what my tester console app spat out.  Feel free to plug it into a test app of your own and let me know if you get different results.

Comment: This didn't achieve the required result for me either.

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar setup working like this: derive `AchievementsList` from `List<Achievement>`, decorate it with the `XmlTypeAttribute` and `XmlRootAttribute`, and also decorate `Achievement` with `XmlTypeAttribute`:

```
[XmlType(TypeName = "Achievements", Namespace="http://www.mynamespace.com")]
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "Achievements", Namespace="http://www.mynamespace.com")]
public class AchievementsList : List<Achievement>
{
}

[XmlType(TypeName = "Achievement", Namespace="http://www.mynamespace.com")]
public class Achievement
{
    ...
}
```

I also decorated my service implementation with the `XmlSerializerFormat` attribute so I can avoid the usual `DataContract` serialization.

Answer (score 1):

I asked a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5773312/deserialize-arrayof-in-xml-to-list) on how to deserialize the XML produced by a WCF webservice method that returns `List<SomeType>`.

The XML has a root named `<ArrayOfSomeType>` and in order to deserialize that back into `List<SomeType>` one must use `DataContractSerializer` instead of `XmlSerializer`, since they are not compatible.