# Deserialize <ArrayOf> in XML to List<>

Tags: .net, xml, wcf, list, serialization

I have trouble deserializing the result from my WCF webservice. The method returns a `List<RecipeEntity>`, which is serialized to XML as shown below. When I try to deserialize I just get an exception, shown below. It seems I cannot deserialize `<ArrayOfRecipe>` to `List<RecipeEntity>`. Note that `RecipeEntity` is mapped by contract name to `Recipe`.

After searching I see many propose XmlArray and XmlElement attributes, but as far as I can tell they do not apply here on the `GetRecipes()` method. I have only seen them used on fields of serialized classes.

I know I could wrap the `List<RecipeEntity>` in a `RecipeList` class and return that instead, but I would rather deserialize directly to List<> for any given type.

Exception:

```
System.InvalidOperationException was caught
  Message=There is an error in XML document (1, 2).
  StackTrace:
       at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Deserialize(XmlReader xmlReader, String encodingStyle, Object events)
       at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Deserialize(XmlReader xmlReader, String encodingStyle)
       at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Deserialize(XmlReader xmlReader)
       at GroceriesAppSL.Pages.Home.GetRecipesCallback(RestResponse response)
  InnerException: System.InvalidOperationException
       Message=<ArrayOfRecipe xmlns='Groceries.Entities'> was not expected.
       StackTrace:
            at Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationReaderList1.Read5_Recipe()
       InnerException:
```

Data contract:

```
[DataContract(Name = "Recipe", Namespace = "Groceries.Entities")]
public class RecipeEntity
{
    [DataMember] public int Id;
    [DataMember] public string Name;
    [DataMember] public string Description;
}
```

Implementation:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IMyService
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebGet(ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml, UriTemplate = "Recipes/{username}")]
    List<RecipeEntity> GetRecipes(string username);
}

public class MyService : IMyService
{
    public List<RecipeEntity> GetRecipes(string username)
    {
        return _recipeDB.Recipes.Select(ToEntity).ToList();
    }
}
```

Example XML result, for illustration purposes only.

```
<ArrayOfRecipe xmlns="Groceries.Entities" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<Recipe>
<Id>139</Id>
<Name>ExampleRecipe</Name>
<Description>5 L milk;4 eggs</Description>
</Recipe>
<Recipe>...</Recipe>
<Recipe>...</Recipe>
<Recipe>...</Recipe>
...
</ArrayOfRecipe>
```

Deserialization code:

```
using (var xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(response.Content)))
{
    var xs = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(List<RecipeEntity>));
    var recipes = (List<RecipeEntity>)xs.Deserialize(xmlReader);
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are using `DataContractSerializer` to serialize and `XmlSerializer` to deserialize. Those two doesn't use the same approach. You must either use `DataContractSerializer` in your deserialization method or you must mark your operation or service with `XmlSerializerFormat` attribute (in such case WCF will use `XmlSerializer` instead of `DataContractSerializer`). `DataContract` and `DataMember` attributes are only for `DataContractSerializer`. `XmlSerializer` uses its own attributes defined in `System.Xml.Serialization` namespace.

Answer (score 2):

Simply first you get the response stream and then use the DataContractSerealizer to deserealize it.

DeSerealization code:

```
using(Stream answer=webResponse.GetResponseStream())
    {
     DataContractSerializer xmlSer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(RecipeEntity[]));
     var RecipeList = (RecipeEntity[])xmlSer.ReadObject(answer);
    }
```

[c#](/questions/tagged/c%23)